# Show all mySQL records where column value does not exist

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress database, which uses extended profiles / buddypress.

I need to get data of users that have not entered a value for a specific field in extended profiles.

The tables are

`BKLU1n5llU_bp_xprofile_data` & `BKLU1n5llU_users`

I want to get a list of all the users that haven't entered a value for the field id ='211'

the table `BKLU1n5llU_bp_xprofile_data` contains the columns `field_id`, `value`, `user_id`

The problem i am facing is that if a user hasn't entered a value, there is no input in the database for the field_id '211'

SELECT * FROM BKLU1n5llU_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = '211' AND value = ''

Does anyone know a way i can get a list of users that have not got anything entered for that specific field_id?

Thanks

Comment: try `SELECT u.id
FROM BKLU1n5llU_users u
LEFT JOIN BKLU1n5llU_bp_xprofile_data pd
ON u.id = pd.user_id
AND pd.field_id = '211'
WHERE pd.value IS NULL;` ?

Comment: Or `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.